# Encryption Program Swapping?

Tags: c, encryption

I was planning on creating an encryption program. Basically swap anything that is from the normal "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" to ""thequickbrownfxjmpsvlazydg".

For example, If I were to key in. "abc" it would result as "the".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void encrypt(char *text, char *map);
void decrypt(char *text, char *map);

int main()
{

    char a[] = {'a','b','c','d','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    char b[] = {'t','h','e','q','u','i','c','k','b','r','o','w','n','f','x','j','m','p','s','v','l','a','z','y','d','g'};
    char *textptr;
    char *mapptr;

    textptr = a;
    mapptr = b;

    encrypt(textptr, mapptr);

    return 0;
}

void encrypt(char *text, char *map)
{
    char string[100];
    int len;
    int x = 0, y = 0, l = 1;

    printf("Please enter the string: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    len = strlen(string);

    for (x = 0; x < len; x++)
    {
    for (y = 0; y < 26; y++)
    {
    if(text[x] == map[y])
    text[x] = map[y];
    }
    }

    printf("The Ciphertext is: %s", string);
}
```

---

and the output is the same plain text that was inputted.. can you guys help me on this?

Comment: so `map` comes from... ?? And you're trying to invoke `strcpy` on *characters*; not strings. This shouldn't even *compile*.

Comment: @devnull this is an assignment that I've been tasked to. I Know it's not a proper encryption or god knows what it is, I Just do it out for marks..

Comment: @devnull I've tried it before hand, and wasted hours since last night on reading again and again, the logic is there, but the syntax is the problem. Not everyone has a precocious ability about solving computer problems..

Comment: @devnull It's a keyed, reversible transformation of plaintext into ciphertext., so calling it encryption is fine. In this case it's a classical keyword based substitution cipher. But like most classical ciphers it's not secure.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

```
strcpy (string[q],map[r]);
```

You're passing two `char`s to `strcpy()` instead of `char *`. To replace a single character, just do

```
string[q] = map[r];
```

**Edit: the new code**

```
if(text[x] == map[y])
   text[x] = map[y];
```

That obviously changes nothing. It should be

```
if( string[x] == text[y] )
   string[x] = map[y];
```

Comment: SOrry.. that's a different code that I've been working before.. here's the correct one..

Comment: I don't know, you beat me or I beat you on posting the answer first. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
 if(text[x] == map[y])
   text[x] = map[y];
```

Use:

```
 if(string[x] == text[y])
   string[x] = map[y];
```

Comment: Let's say it has been a dead race :-)

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt : Ya !! :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using simply single for loop. and you need to define array a[].

```
for (x = 0; x < strlen(string); x++)
{
string[x]=map[string[x]-'a'];

}
```

**Modified code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void encrypt(char *map);

int main()
{

    char b[] = {'t','h','e','q','u','i','c','k','b','r','o','w','n','f','x','j','m','p','s','v','l','a','z','y','d','g'};
    char *mapptr;
    mapptr = b;
    encrypt(mapptr);
    return 0;
}

void encrypt(char *map)
{
    char string[100];
    int x = 0;

    printf("Please enter the string: ");
    scanf("%s", string);

    for (x = 0; x < strlen(string); x++)
    {
    if(islower(string[x]))
    string[x]=map[string[x]-'a'];

    }

    printf("The Ciphertext is: %s\n", string);
}
```